# VS2010 custom Template IWizard

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-templates

I am just learning about custom VSTemplates I have created a wizard using IWizard,

I have a solution folder which I need to change the name from `testname` to `$safeprojectname$`

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this (and related children pages) article at MSDN - [How to: Substitute Parameters in a Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185311.aspx)

Comment: You're welcome! Please feel free to mark it as answer. Thanks!